# php ends when identifies the ">" symbol

Tags: php, html, operators, symbols, doctype

Hi i'm facing a very weird problem.. I had me html code begin with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

When i add some php code on top with < ? php, and ends with ?> its all good, 
 unless i use somewhere the ">" symbol for example "$variable => $value in a foreach..."

it ends identifying php code here, displays the rest after ">" as text in html body, and dont execute anything. 
What is going on..?

Thank you.

Comment: uh, something to do with `php.ini` i think, but i can't salvage it from my memories..

Comment: Can you give the actual code it's causing the error on? A little hard to get to figure out what's going on without it

Comment: It doesn't do with php.ini it detects firstly in Dreamweaver it changes the color of "<?php" and stops at ">" and secondly in Xamp (apache) when i run it.
    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {

When it founds the ">" symbol the rest " $value) { ....etc it displays on html.